# POST request timeout ONLY on device using NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying to make POST request using NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest. It works great when I run app on Simulator, but on real device I got timeout error (NSURLErrorDomain" - code: -1001), my server works ok

My code:

```
 NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                    timeoutInterval:30];


[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSError *error = nil;
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Why I see timeout? and it is only on device?

Comment: check your internet connection. It might be using 2G or low speed internet.

Comment: I am connected with WIFI - it is ok, other apps works fine

Comment: you do it on the main thread?

Comment: Yes, I tried to wrap it in  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{